# Is there any algorithm which can parse or decode the String results obtained from BarCode Scanner using Zxing?

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

Is there any algorithm which can parse or decode the String results obtained from BarCode Scanner using Zxing?

I want to extract Lot number or serial number from the scanned result. Is there any standard algorithm to do so?

I currently use,

```
    String lotNumber=scanResults.substring(24,26);  
if (lotNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("10")){  
             System.out.println("Lot numberrrrrrrrrrr " + a.substring(26,a.length()));  
         }
```

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 0):

Look at the class `ResultParser`. It will try to parse the result string as something more meaningful. For example "mailto:foo@example.org" would come back as `EmailParsedResult`, letting you know it's an email address and parsing out the address for you.

I am not sure what this lot number is -- it's not well-known and so not implemented outside your system. But yes you can find a lot of this kind of logic in the project already, which you can perhaps reuse and modify.

Comment: Lot numbers are .. fairly well marked ([AI 23](http://www.adams1.com/ucc128.html)) though.

Answer (score -1):

no there is no magic in java or any language which can tell you what is that data for which that bar code was generated. You should know the data and should know its content type (json, xml etc) and then use the parser. Or if its not as per the defined standards (any random string) than do as what you are doing.

Comment: but if we can encode data as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GS1-128 for GS-128, there should be something for decoding right?

Comment: thats what I wanna say, you must know what you have used to encode the data. Then only you can find/ decide what needs to be used to decode/decrypt it. But which way/ algo you should use, cant be told programmatically.

Comment: okay.. thank you. it means that Zxing has nothing as such other than giving format and scanned results.

Comment: yes :) its just "what is encoded as bar code is what you get".